# ROUND() doesn't allow JOIN as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query (using SQL Server) that serves to delete all rows in one table that exist in another. The problem is that one of the columns `Amount` is a decimal value and in one table the values are rounded and in the other they are not. I thought by using the `ROUND` function it would treat both as the same but it doesn't. I am using `ROUND(value, 2)` and here is an example column where I would have expected the rounded values to be equal.

```
+----------------------+----------------------+
| Amount Column TableA | Amount Column TableB |
+----------------------+----------------------+
|        1703.98       |       1703.975       |
+----------------------+----------------------+


DELETE t1 
FROM [dbo].[TableA] t1
JOIN [dbo].[TableB] t2 ON ISNULL(t1.[Account], '') = ISNULL(t2.[Account], '') 
                       AND ISNULL(t1.[Date], '') = ISNULL(t2.[Date], '') 
                       AND ISNULL(ROUND(t1.[Amount], 2, 0), '') = ISNULL(ROUND(t2.[Amount], 2, 0), '')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the ISNULL result '' causing the two numbers to be compared as strings?  '1703.98' <> '1703.980', even though 1703.98 = 1703.980

Comment: Bad, bad data structure.  `1703.975` might really be `1703.97499999999`.

Comment: Try like this ROUND(ISNULL(t2.[Amount], 0), 2, 0)

Comment: @JeffBreadner . . . No.  The numbers take precedence.

Comment: Is the type of the `Amount` column the same in both tables? What is it?

Comment: May be try `Convert(nvarchar(255), IsNull(ROUND(t1.[Amount], 2, 0), ''))`, make it string and see if the two value the same?

Comment: looks like one of the amount is a `decimal / numeric` and the other are `float`. use `convert() or cast()` to convert to decimal and compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just round to the whole number?

```
 DELETE TableA
 FROM TableA T1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB T2
 ON T1.Account = T2.Account
    AND T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]

 WHERE 
 ROUND(T1.Amount,0) = ROUND(T2.Amount,0)
```

Or if not, cast both numbers the same:

```
    DELETE #TableA
    FROM #TableA T1
    JOIN #TableB T2
    ON T1.Account = T2.Account
      AND T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
      AND ROUND(CAST(T1.Amount AS decimal(9,2)),2,0) = ROUND(CAST(T2.Amount AS decimal(9,2)),2,0)
```

Comment: This worked. The `CAST(value as Decimal(9,2))` seem to do the trick